# Python function not being called

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I stumbled on a problem with functions:

```py
from tkinter import *

count = 0

def create_window():
    global count
    new_window = Toplevel()
    count += 1
    if count > 2:
        destroy_windowroot
    print(count)

def destroy_windowroot():
    window.destroy()
    print("something is going on")

window = Tk()

b = Button(window, text="create new window dont go past 2", command=create_window)
b.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

*this code should create a window every time the button is pressed and counts how many times its clicked so it can close the window when it reach's a certain number*

It does count correctly but for some reason the destroy_windowroot function is not being called
am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, parentheses. You meant to call the function: `destroy_windowroot()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call a function, you need to use the function name followed by brackets (parenthesis). For example:

```py
def my_function():
  print("Hello from a function")

my_function()
```

In your case, you need to replace `destroy_windowroot` with `destroy_windowroot()`.